# How to install MEEP on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, meep

I installed recently Ubuntu 14.04 from www.ubuntu.com/downloads on my 64 bit laptop. I have a problem in installing meep software on this. It is not available in Ubuntu store and I tried command `sudo apt-get install meep h5utils` but this also didn't work.

But it is showing on web that Ubuntu 14.04 has `meep` in its store. Please help me installing meep.

Comment: what's the output of `sudo apt-get install meep h5utils`?

Answer (score 0):

**Enable universe repository**

Open dash and type `Software sources`

[image: type <code>software sources</code> in Dash]

then open software sources and click on the the universe repository .

[image: select "Community maintained Open Source Software (universe)"]

Close and reload cache

[image: reload cache]

Now, you can run:

```
sudo apt-get install meep h5utils
```

to install `meep`. In some cases, you also have to enable the `source code` option (last option in the figure 2) for `meep` to be installed.